# Refreshing an Activity from service when Active

Tags: android

I've an app where I wish to update the Activity (List activity to be precise) only when the activity from Service is in foreground (Active)

I can use ListActivity Intent but the problem is this brings up activity even when its in background.

I also considered using registerDataSetObserver on ListAdapter but that mandates that cursor should be updated. Updating the Cursor from external service may not be feasible.

Do we have a generic solution to this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Do we have a generic solution to this
>   ?

Probably a dozen of them. Here are a few:

- Have the activity register a listener object with the service in `onResume()` and remove it in `onPause()`
- Send a private broadcast, picked up by the activity via `registerReceiver()` when it is in the foreground
- Have the activity supply a "pending result"-style `PendingIntent` to the service
- Use a `ResultReceiver`
- Use a `ContentProvider`, with the activity holding onto a `Cursor` from the provider, and the service updating the provider

[This set of projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/) demonstrates the first three, in the context of remote services.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have a centralized place. I consider this to be the best solution.
 Check this out:

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/3667282#3667282)