# How can I detect if my Android app is displayed?

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a service that runs in the background doing various client/server connections.  How can I check in my running service if any screen from my app is displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the list of running processes and check if yours is in foreground with the following code:

```
ActivityManager actMngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = actMngr.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo pi : runningAppProcesses) {
    if (getPackageName().equals(pi.processName)) {

        boolean inForeground = pi.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
    }
}
```

Check more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html

Comment: You may want IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE, not FOREGROUND, in case your app is visible but has a dialog from another service on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

[Refreshing an Activity from service when Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225696/refreshing-an-activity-from-service-when-active)
a few options:

•Have the activity register a listener object with the service in onResume() and remove it in onPause()

•Send a private broadcast, picked up by the activity via registerReceiver() when it is in the foreground

•Have the activity supply a "pending result"-style PendingIntent to the service

•Use a ResultReceiver

•Use a ContentProvider, with the activity holding onto a Cursor from the provider, and the service updating the provider

see here https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/ for a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a service is running use

```
 ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)  MyApp.getSharedApplication().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (CTConstants.MyService_Name.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            //Your service is running
        }
    }
```

if you don't want to generalize this as a common function then replace the first line with

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```